# Ubuntu 13.04 Installation on VM Hanged

Tags: system-installation

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 on Virtual Machine but during the installation of software in (Retrieving file 40 of 102) it is hanged and not going forward. would you please guide me what to do to solve the problem.

Comment: start over with a new install, it's always easier!

Answer (score 0):

Re-attempt the installation. This time, ensure that you **do not** check '[Download updates while installing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcL5Y.png)'. I installed Ubuntu both yesterday and the day prior, and having this checked added an extra ~1h to the install process. If applicable, you may wish to use the regular Ubuntu ISO Installation and not the [Network Installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads).

After successful installation, you may use the Software Updater or `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` in the terminal to update.